# instruction operands size error when defining and calling a macro that receive different data types. Using masm32

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, masm, masm32

I am trying writing a macro which should receive a `BYTE`, `WORD` or `DWORD` type integer and print it on the screen. I try using the `SIZEOF` function in the macro definition in order to send the different data types to registers of different size, but the error happens where the macro is called. Here is the full code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
oneByte BYTE 42h
twoByte WORD 1423h
fourByte DWORD 1950123Dh
errorMessage BYTE "ERROR INPUT!!!", 0
.code
mWriteInt MACRO theInt
    mov eax, sizeof theInt
    cmp eax, 1
    je isonebyte
    cmp eax, 2
    je istwobyte
    cmp eax, 4
    je isfourbyte
    jmp error
isonebyte:
    mov eax, 0
    mov al, theInt
    jmp over
istwobyte:
    mov eax, 0
    mov ax, theInt
    jmp over
isfourbyte:
    mov eax, theInt
    jmp over
error:
    mov edx, offset errorMessage
    call WriteString
    call crlf
over:
    call writeInt
ENDM

MAIN PROC
mWriteInt oneByte   ;<----ERROR HAPPENS HERE
call dumpregs
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

the error message shows:
A2022   instruction operands must be the same size
A2022   instruction operands must be the same size

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach with checking the size at runtime requires the assembler to generate machine code for all possible code paths, even ones that may not be taken at runtime.

If one or more of those code paths result in illegal operand combinations, then obviously that will fail.

You'll have to move your size check so that it occurs at compile time instead. Something like:

```
IF SIZEOF theInt EQ SIZEOF BYTE
    mov eax, 0
    mov al, theInt
ELSEIF SIZEOF theInt EQ SIZEOF WORD
.. etc ..
ENDIF
call writeInt
```

---

If you're ok with sign-extension of the argument instead of zero-extension you could probably simplify all that to:

```
push theInt
pop eax
call writeInt
```

**Edit:** This approach would not work for an `r/m8` argument.

Comment: This is 32-bit mode so we definitely have `movzx dword, byte` available, no need to use a clunky `mov eax,0`.  Just check for sizes != each other and use `movzx`, else `mov`.  If `movzx` isn't encodeable then the source wasn't a byte or word, or a dword which would have picked `mov`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That was from OP's code. My answer was just to show how to do compile-time size/type checking of macro parameters.

Comment: Always keep in mind that someone looking for a solution to a problem might come across your code and copy/paste it.  Including poor code in your answers could hurt future readers.  Also `movzx` shares a mnemonic for byte and word so it simplifies the amount of cases, very much worth mentioning.